# Bootstrap align content in columns

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5. I am having trouble moving the "create new" button flush to the right side and aligned with the end of my table.

[image]

Here is my bootstrap code

```
<div class="border backgroundWhite">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <h2 class="text-info">Environment List</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <partial name="_CreateButtonPartial" />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
        @if (Model.Data.Count() > 0)
        {
            <table class="table table-striped border">
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th>Environment</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Data)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Environment)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <partial name="_TableButtonPartial" model="item.Id" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <div page-model="@Model.DataPaging" page-classes-enabled="true" page-class="btn border"
                 page-class-normal="btn btn-light" page-class-selected="btn btn-info active"
                 class="btn-group float-right">
            </div>
            <br />
        }
        else
        {
            <p>No environment exists....</p>
        }
</div>
```

I have tried multiple combinations of justify-content-end align-content-end

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

just found the solution

float-end

Once that was applied it worked out perfectly

```
<p>
   <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-info float-end"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp; Create New</a>
</p>
```